# Postgres: design table to save associated pairs

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using Postgres.

Having a chat bot I need to create a table to store matches:

A paired with B and consequently B paired with A.

I was considering if create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE matches (user_a INT, user_b INT);
```

And save the pair once like:

```
INSERT INTO matches (1, 2);
```

Or twice like:

```
INSERT INTO matches (1, 2);
INSERT INTO matches (2, 1);
```

I will need to query the table also with only one column to check user “1”

In the first case I will need to use:

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE user_a=1 or user_b=1;
```

In the second case I can query just with:

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE user_a=1;
```

Because saving both the sides of the match.

I also will need to join this table with another table.
In the first case I need to do

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.user_a=users.user_id OR matches.user_b=users.user_id;
```

In the second case I can avoid the OR doing:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN matches ON matches.user_a=users.user_id;
```

Which of the two approaches of using the same table  would be the best practice?
I think the first one could save half of the space, but the second one maybe could be more normalized and better for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `OR` kills `JOIN` performance.  It is much harder for the optimizer to optimize.  That suggests that storing two rows in a table rather than 1 is often going result in better performance -- perhaps counter-intuitively, because it doubles the data values.

That said, if you do go for the more concise form, there are things you can do, such as:

```
SELECT u.*, m.*
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     (matches m CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      (VALUES (m.user_a), (m.user_b)
      ) v(user_id)
     )
     ON v.user_id = u.user_id ;
```

This should use an index on `users(user_id)`.  That said, your version or `IN` should use an index on that table.  But it is much harder to use an index on `matches`.